# Trouble with scrollIntoView javascript

Tags: javascript, function, scroll, js-scrollintoview

I am trying to get my JavaScript to scroll something into view upon me clicking a `div`. When I click it nothing happens.

I've done a few things to troubleshoot: console.log in the `scrollToAbout` section works fine and I can run other functions like changing `innerHTML` just fine. ScrollIntoView just doesn't appear to do anything. No errors in the dev console.

HTML for the `div` I'm clicking

```
<div class="lander">
  <div class="intro"></div>
  <div id="navbar">
    <a href="#" class="navlist hyperlink" id="aboutButton">about</a>
    <a href="#" class="navlist hyperlink" id="contactButton">contact</a>
    <a href="#" class="navlist hyperlink" id="funButton">fun</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

HTML for the `div` I want to scroll to:

```
<div class="row hello col-12 p-0 m-0" id="aboutSection">
  <img class="xyz col-12 col-md-6" src="xyz" alt="">
  <p class="aboutme col-12 col-md-6"> THIS SECTION </p>
</div>
```

then here is the JS I've written:

```
let aboutButton = document.querySelector('#aboutButton');
let aboutSection = document.querySelector('#aboutSection');

aboutButton.onclick = function(){
    scrollToAbout()
};


function scrollToAbout(){
    aboutSection.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth'});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `href` attribute on the anchor (`href="#"`) is causing the page to scroll to the top.

As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-href):

> You can use `href="#top"` or the empty fragment (**`href="#"`**) to link to the top of the current page...

You should instead remove it altogether, or, if you want to preserve the anchor styling, set the href to `javascript:void(0)`.

Also,

```
aboutButton.onclick = function(){
    scrollToAbout()
};
```

is redundant. Simply `aboutButton.onclick = scrollToAbout` does the trick.

```js
let aboutButton = document.querySelector('#aboutButton');
let aboutSection = document.querySelector('#aboutSection');

function scrollToAbout() {
  aboutSection.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
};


aboutButton.onclick = scrollToAbout;
```

```css
#navbar {
  margin-bottom: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="lander">
  <div class="intro"></div>
  <div id="navbar">
    <a class="navlist hyperlink" id="aboutButton">about</a>
    <a href="#" class="navlist hyperlink" id="contactButton">contact</a>
    <a href="#" class="navlist hyperlink" id="funButton">fun</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row hello col-12 p-0 m-0" id="aboutSection">
  <img class="xyz col-12 col-md-6" src="xyz" alt="">
  <p class="aboutme col-12 col-md-6"> THIS SECTION </p>
</div>
```